# Getting "Application tried to present modally an active controller" error for unknown reason

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

One of my navigation buttons results in another view controller being preset end. Pretty standard stuff. However I wind up getting an error when I present it. I'm running this code:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Channel" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HIChannelSelectionNavigationController"];
HIChannelSelectionViewController *vc = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
vc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The result is an error that says: `Application tried to present modally an active controller <HIContactsViewController: 0x1769cb80>.` HIContactsViewController is the view controller that I'm presenting from, not the one I'm presenting (which makes this odd). One other thing to add: I tried doing this without the storyboard and still got the error.

**Update**

One additional piece of insight is that not attempting to load the sub-view controllers in the nav avoids the error from taking place (although now I can't respond to delegate calls).

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"self = %@  vc = %@", self, vc);` to check this error. If view controller's addresses are equal you should check the way you create your current View Controller (self).

Comment: Duh, I figured it out. I was presenting the view controller not the navigation. Although that error still makes no sense.

Comment: I think the error does make sense. The child view controller already has a parent view controller (the nav controller), so it's "active" (i.e., inside the view controller hierarchy) and it wouldn't make sense to present it.

Comment: @bgfriend0 got it. So you think it would have been better (in the broken case) to present from the nav? I don't think that's possible though. (or at least not recommended)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. I think, given any one particular sub-VC, you have to make the choice to display it inside a nav VC or present it--not both at the same time. So if you were in the nav VC and hadn't push or presented the sub-VC yet, you could do one or the other. Technically I guess you could instantiate the sub-VC twice and push one instance and present the other. It boils down to not pushing and presenting the same VC object at the same time.